# Is it possible to hide the column _id in the CKAN Data Explorer default preview?

Tags: ckan

When uploading a CSV file to DataStore, it adds an internal index column `_id`.
**Is it possible to hide it in the default preview? Or can we set an existing id column as an index column?** Currently if our dataset has its own id column, there are two id columns in the preview.

Another problem: DataExplorer uses a rather strange sorting order (for example, row 14th on the attached screen).
**Can we set the default sorting based on the id column?**

[image: Default preview with _id column]

Comment: You can override the extension with your own extension and then do as you like. But I don't think there's a setting or config option for this.